# How to find Google Test with find_package using CMake on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmake, googletest

I have tried without success to use the `find_package` function in CMake to make use of a pre-built "system wide" version of GTest in Windows. Here is a minimal, reproducible example of my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
if(NOT GTEST_LIBRARY)
    message("GTest not found!")
endif()
```

I try to generate build files using the following command:

```
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015" -DGTEST_ROOT="c:\Libs\googletest"
```

The `c:\Libs\googletest` path contains my pre-built GTest (with header files and binaries). I have studied the `FindGTest.cmake` file in my CMake installation (I use CMake version 3.13.3) and tried all kinds of folder structure, but I always get the following error message:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR
  GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindGTest.cmake:196 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)
```

**Has anyone succeeded in using `find_package` for GTest in Windows?** If so, how did you do it?

Comment: Do you have the file `C:\Libs\googletest\include\gtest\gtest.h`?

Comment: Yes. Most of my tries have included `C:\Libs\googletest\include\gtest` and `C:\Libs\googletest\include\gmock`.

Comment: There should be a file somewhere called `GTestConfig.cmake` your root should point to that instead.

Comment: If there is not, compile GTest using CMake

Comment: There is no such file. I have built GTest using CMake (since there is no official build or installer). I am just trying to put the built binaries and header files in `c:\Libs\googletest` in such way that the `find_package` function together with `FindGTest.cmake` recognizes the library.

Comment: [`FindGTest.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindGTest.cmake) is part of CMake, not GTest. A long while ago I had to do something similar on Linux, and `GTEST_ROOT` needed to point to the actual build folder instead of the top-level source folder, so you might need to fiddle with the path until you get it right. There's `GTEST_MSVC_SEARCH` also.

Answer (score 2):

First you must build **AND** install Googletest using CMake build system

Then try to locate the *GTestConfig.cmake* file in the installation directory

So now you can add this path to the [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) variable.

Thus configuring your project using CMake, it should be able to *find_package(GTest)* using the usual [search procedure](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure).

So you just have to use **GTest::GTest** to consume it (i.e. *target_link_libraries(.... GTest::GTest)* ).

note: For people using FetchContent/add_subdirectory(googletest) beware google/googletest still **not provide** ALIAS target see https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/2429

Comment: You most definitively don't need to use CMake to either fetch or build GTest. If you install GTest through a system package manager like `apt`, `find_package(GTest REQUIRED)` should work file (been there, done that). The [_recommended_ way](http://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html) is to use `FetchContent_Declare`, but it's not _required_.

Comment: user is on windows so package manager is a dream ^^;
note: Chocolatey doesn't provide it.